# Capitalize 'List of Tables' and 'List of Figures' in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, capitalization

In my Table of Contents, the first two entries are List of Tables and List of Figures with the roman page numbers referring to where these lists actually are. I need to make these two entries all capitalized like LIST OF TABLES and LIST OF FIGURES. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

By default there is a difference in what is passed as a contents-related entry and what is set within the document. Since you have little control over this when setting `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, the example below intervenes by passing the LoF/LoT entries using `\MakeUppercase`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocbibind}

\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\ADDCONTENTSLINE}[3]{%
  \oldaddcontentsline{#1}{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\newcommand{\CAPinToC}{\let\addcontentsline\ADDCONTENTSLINE}
\newcommand{\noCAPinToC}{\let\addcontentsline\oldaddcontentsline}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\CAPinToC% All entries in ToC will be CAPITALIZED from here on
\listoftables

\listoffigures

\noCAPinToC% Rever to original \addcontentsline formatting
\section{A section}

\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You can activate this type of ToC-related formatting using `\CAPinToC` (or revert back to the original definition using `\noCAPinToC`).

Comment: When I call `\listoffigures`, the chapter heading appears as 'List of Figures', while the ToC entry appears as 'List of figures'. How do I remove the capital F from the chapter heading?

Comment: @Hans: Can you provide a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that replicates this behaviour? Something I can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing? You can use [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: here is the first few lines of code: https://pastebin.com/c4pqtfwx

Answer (score 3):

To change the chapter heading of Figures list, use the following command:

```
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{List of figures}
```

after `\begin{document}` and before the `\listoffigures` command.

Similarly to change the chapter heading for Table list, you can use:

```
\renewcommand*\listtablename{List of tables}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!