# Cannot compile after putting table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in,bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[rm,tiny]{titlesec} %added this to change the chapter title's font as default regular text font.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\underline\normalfont\normalsize\centering}

\newlength{\depthofsumsign}
\setlength{\depthofsumsign}{\depthof{$\sum$}}
\newlength{\totalheightofsumsign}
\newlength{\heightanddepthofargument}

\usepackage{pdflscape,booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit} 
\usepackage[font=it,skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption} % italic text for captions

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[3pt]                                               % left margin
{}%
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                               % numbered entry format
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    }
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}                        % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.99pc]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]                                                  % below code (e.g vertical space)


%to put page numbers as the header
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\centering}{}{0pt}{}
\titlelabel{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-25pt}{4pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\centering}{}{0pt}{}

%koleygr: Redefining chapter to include \thispagestyle{fancy}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\def\chapter{%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred section can not have parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter*{#2}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{
\oldchapter*{#1}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter[#1]{#2}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\oldchapter{#1}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}
}
\makeatother

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}



\begin{document}
```

I was using this same set of codes earlier, and it was working fine. Then I wanted to change the format of the titles, 'List of figures,' and 'List of tables' into all caps, i.e. "LIST OF FIGURES," and "LIST OF TABLES." So I used a bunch of codes. After they showed error, I undid everything and came back to the original state, but it stopped compiling.

Finally, I got rid of `\tableofcontents` code, and it compiled. But, now I cannot add the table of contents.

It is showing a ton of errors. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

For my codes for table of contents, I am just using the normal bunch of codes:

```
\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

\listoftables

\pagebreak

\listoffigures

\pagebreak
```

Is there some defect in my codes, somewhere?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I added some chapters and some sections, and then using `\tableofcontents` doesn't make any errors: I got this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWj4M.png).

Comment: You might have put `\tableofcontents` and other stuff out of scope of `\begin{document}..\end{document}`. I don't get any error compiling your code.

Comment: @JouleV, I just made a completely new document, and copy-pasted the entire code, and it works fine. But I went back to the original file, and it would still not compile, unless I get rid of the table of contents code. Not sure why that's happening! May be I will use the new document from now onward. [And I gotta learn how to use this forum better, thanks for your comment :) ]

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah Yeah, not sure why that's happening just to that one document.

Comment: @SamyamShrestha It is very strange. Maybe you should see if you have made any fatal settings inside `document` of your original file. Do you have any suspicious commands inside `document`?

Comment: Well you should write those lines inside document scope.

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah You mean `\tableofcontents` right? That is within the document scope, I double checked. It's weird. But thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @SamyamShrestha yeah exactly. It must look like this: `\begin{document} \tableofcontents \listoftables \listoffigures ... \end{document}`.

Comment: @JouleV As I noted before, I used the codes to capitalize LIST OF TABLES and LIST OF FIGURES titles. I used the codes given in the two answers at this page: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337881/capitalize-list-of-tables-and-list-of-figures-in-table-of-contents. However, after failing to compile any, I got rid of them, but only then this problem would arise.

Comment: And I still cannot capitalize those titles. haha

Comment: If moving content to fresh file or renaming tex files clears an issue it usually indicates the original file still has borked auxiliaries so try the  corresponding editor "clean" command

Comment: If you don't have a `clean` feature, delete the aux and toc files directly.